# Store count of unique characters in a temporary variable

Tags: python, dictionary, key

Background: For a previous task I needed to count and store unique characters from a key in a dictionary(beginning of Rubik's cube solver)

Issue: Afterwards ive seen that the amount of keys I have are incrementing because I have stored the count in result which is later used as a return value, and was wondering how to instead store the counts in a temporary variable?

```py
result={}
encodedCube = parms.get('cube',None)

for keys in encodedCube:
   result[keys] = result.get(keys,0) + 1
```

How would I go about using a temporary variable that is destroyed later?(sorry I'm very very new to Python)

Example of issue :

```py
def test_check_020_shouldReturnOKOnSingleReturnKey(self):
parm = {'op':'check',
        'cube':'bbbbbbbbbyyyyyyyyyeeeeeeeeeoooooooootttttttttuuuuuuuuu'}
expectedResult = 1
result = check._check(parm)
status = result.get('status', None)
self.assertEqual(expectedResult, len(result))
```

would say

```py
AssertionError: 1 != 7
```

Comment: look at `collections.Counter` or `collections.defaultdict` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do what a [counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) was made for. As an example,

```
from collections import Counter

parm = {'op':'check',
        'cube':'bbbbbbbbbyyyyyyyyyeeeeeeeeeoooooooootttttttttuuuuuuuuu'}
c = Counter(parm['cube'])
print(dict(c))
```

The result:

```
{'b': 9, 'y': 9, 'e': 9, 'o': 9, 't': 9, 'u': 9}
```